# Add method to jQuery validation without submit button

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I have a form that needs to be validated but it does not have a submit button. 
So to get the validation done, I followed the example on http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid

which tells to call .valid() function.
So i added the following code which worked fine:

```
            $(".getcars").click(function() {
                valid = $("#form1").valid();
                if(valid){
                    ajaxCall();
                }

            });
```

Now I want to add more rules to the validation field , so i tried

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersandnumonly", function(value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9A-Za-z]+$/i.test(value);
                    }, "Letters and numbers only ");
jQuery.validator.addMethod("nowhitespace", function(value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || /^\S+$/i.test(value);
            }, "No white space please"); 

            $(".getcars").click(function() {
                valid = $("#form1").valid(
                {
                rules: {
                    postal_code: {
                        maxlength: 6,
                        lettersandnumonly: true,
                        nowhitespace: true
                    }
                }
            });
                if(valid){
                    ajaxCall();
                }

            });
```

but this is not working. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong while adding the rule?

Comment: btw , the field I am trying to validate is
    <div class="label">Please enter your Postal Code or a part of it!</div>
    <input type="text" id="postal_code" name="postal_code" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rule` definitions go in the initial call to [`validate()`](http://rocketsquared.com/wiki/Plugins/Validation/validate). Since `valid()` only works on forms that have had `validate()` called on them, I'm assuming you have a line in the code somewhere calling `validate()`:

```
$("#form1").validate();
```

All you should have to do is move your rule definitions into that initial call:

```
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        postal_code: {
            maxlength: 6,
            lettersandnumonly: true,
            nowhitespace: true
        }
    }
});
```

... And then call `.valid()` later like you were doing initially:

```
$(".getcars").click(function() {
    valid = $("#form1").valid();
    if(valid) {
        ajaxCall();
    }
});
```